# How to edit Laravel 7 AbstractHasher or BcryptHasher?

Tags: php, laravel, hash, laravel-7, bcrypt

I'm having some problems trying to extend or change a part of the Laravel Framework. Simply I cannot figure out where I can add or edit so that my changes will not be made in the vendor folder.

Essentially my issue was implementing Password Reset functionality to my React/Laravel application. I use inertia to post the reset password form, and it gives the error as follows:

> ErrorException password_verify() expects parameter 1 to be string,
> array given

I use Bcrypt to hash the passwords, so as a workaround I added a couple lines of code to the check function of vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Hashing/BcryptHasher.php:

> ```
>     if (is_array($value)) {
>        $value = array_values($value)[0];
>   }
> ```

So now the whole function looks like this:

```
public function check($value, $hashedValue, array $options = [])
{
    if ($this->verifyAlgorithm && $this->info($hashedValue)['algoName'] !== 'bcrypt') {
        throw new RuntimeException('This password does not use the Bcrypt algorithm.');
    }
    if (is_array($value)) {
        $value = array_values($value)[0];
    }
    return parent::check($value, $hashedValue, $options);
}
```

I can also make the same change in the parent, AbstractHasher, within its check function and this also resolves the error.

This works, but I need to find a solution to implement this fix without making the changes inside the vendor folder. I deploy the app to google app engine so the changes within the vendor folder will not work in my situation. I just need to know how I can either extend or overwrite the BcryptHasher.php or AbstractHasher.php file properly.

Note: This is my first post here, so hopefully I did not format the message too poorly. If any additional information is required I will provide it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't directly edit vendor files, those will be reset as soon as you update to newer versions, instead of editing the vendor file, update your call to the `check` method instead, that's your part of the application, if you have an array, grab the password from that and send that to `check` instead of editing the vendor file. The vendor files are also local to you and will be downloaded again when you run `composer install` on your server.

Comment: I've answered a question in the past which required to create a custom password hasher / verifier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65663084/487813) it might help you as well. In your case you could extend `BcryptHasher`

Comment: @kim I do understand that I should not edit any of the vendor files because they will not persist, that is why my question is exactly how can I avoid doing this.

Comment: @apokryfos I will give this a try, thanks!

Comment: @Squaaz Why are you busy extending the facade if you can filter from the controller?

Comment: @WahyuKristianto I did separate the password from the request in the controller, but once this was passed off to Bcrypt for some reason it was receiving an array, instead of just the value. Like many problems there is multiple solutions, and this is was the only way for me to get it to work.

On a side note, apokryfos answer worked great, so issue is resolved. Thanks all for the help.

Comment: @Squaaz If you already have a solution, please post it as an answer, so that people out there who have issue like you can be helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the issue, I adapted @apokryfos answer  [How to change login hash bcrypt to hash256](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65662547/how-to-change-login-hash-bcrypt-to-hash256/65663084#65663084) to work with BcryptHasher instead of trying to add a new hasher such as Sha256.

To do this I made the following changes:

**In config/hashing.php**
Set the driver as custombcrypt for my implementation.

> 'driver' => 'custombcrypt',

**In app folder**

I created a folder named Libraries to hold my custom hasher classes. This folder can be named anything.

**In created Libraries folder at app/Libraries**

I created a file CustomBcryptHasher.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Libraries;

use Illuminate\Hashing\BcryptHasher;
use RuntimeException;

class CustomBcryptHasher extends BcryptHasher
{
    /**
     * Check the given plain value against a hash.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @param  string  $hashedValue
     * @param  array  $options
     * @return bool
     *
     * @throws \RuntimeException
     */
    public function check($value, $hashedValue, array $options = [])
    {
        if ($this->verifyAlgorithm && $this->info($hashedValue)['algoName'] !== 'bcrypt') {
            throw new RuntimeException('This password does not use the Bcrypt algorithm.');
        }
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $value = array_values($value)[0];
        }
        return parent::check($value, $hashedValue, $options);
    }

}
```

The most important part of this file is this small portion near the bottom

```
    if (is_array($value)) {
       $value = array_values($value)[0];
  }
```

This checks if the value is an array, and if so will extract the first value and use this for the Bcrypt check.

**In created Libraries folder at app/Libraries**
I add created a file named Hash.php which is a copy of /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Hash.php

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Support\Facades;

/**
 * @method static array info(string $hashedValue)
 * @method static bool check(string $value, string $hashedValue, array $options = [])
 * @method static bool needsRehash(string $hashedValue, array $options = [])
 * @method static string make(string $value, array $options = [])
 *
 * @see \Illuminate\Hashing\HashManager
 */
class Hash extends Facade
{
    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'hash';
    }
}
```

**In app/Providers**
I edited the AuthServiceProvider.php to return my CustomBcryptHasher.php when the custombcrypt driver is called.

To do so, I added this code to the boot() function:

```
Hash::extend('custombcrypt', function () {
    return new CustomBcryptHasher();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, you can use Dependency Injection to pass an appropriate Hasher to your Guard, so if you were to extend BcryptHasher and pass it, your issue would be solved.