# Firebase Auth migration using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, firebase-authentication, laravel-10

next, I have to migrate some Firebase Auth accounts to a Postgres database and my backend is running Laravel 10.
The problem is that the Firebase Auth password algorithm is SCRYPT, I searched and searched and didn't find any packages to deal with this type of algorithm.

Does anyone have an idea how to make it work?

In Firebase Auth returns me the algorithm with the following structure:

```
hash_config {
   algorithm: SCRYPT,
   base64_signer_key: my_code==,
   base64_salt_separator: Bw==,
   rounds: 8,
   mem_cost: 14,
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for a PHP implementation of the SCRYPT hashing algorithm? Because the first result of my [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+scrypt) for that is this promising looking package: https://github.com/DomBlack/php-scrypt

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have this package installed but now I don't know how to configure Laravel to use it instead of the default drivers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65662547/how-to-change-login-hash-bcrypt-to-hash256, but then call the scrypt package you use? Note I'm just [doing searches](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+set+scrypt+hash+for+laravel+auth) at this point for what I think you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, friend. But the links you provided I already went through them days ago.
That's why I asked here, if anyone has had this problem and how it was solved.
Searching on Google and entering the links on the first page I did everything a long time ago.
As I understand Firebase uses modified scrypt, so just testing pure scrypt in laravel or another framework won't help.
https://github.com/firebase/scrypt

I created a ticket on Firebase for support.
Thanks again for the answers

Comment: Just updating... I got what I wanted using a javascript package.
Everything worked!
https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-scrypt

Answer (score 0):

There is no implementation for the Scrypt algorithm in php, but Python actually has it (And Java).

I resolved this problem writing a Python script and calling it from PHP.

I used this Python repository:
https://github.com/JaakkoL/firebase-scrypt-python

I created a laravel controller like this:

```
Router::get('firebase_login', function ( Request $request ){
    $result = null;

    $password = (string) $request->input('password');
    $email = (string) $request->input('email');

    $firebaseModel = FirebaseRegistrantModel::where('email', $email)->first();
    if( $firebaseModel ){

        $password_hash = $firebaseModel->password;
        $salt = $firebaseModel->salt;
        $signer_key = env("FIREBASE_HASH_SIGNER_KEY");
        $salt_separator = env("FIREBASE_HASH_SALT_SEPARATOR");
        $rounds = env("FIREBASE_HASH_ROUNDS");
        $mem_cost = env("FIREBASE_HASH_MEM_COST");

        $process = new \Symfony\Component\Process\Process([
            'python3', base_path().'/scrypt.py',
            $password,
            $password_hash,
            $salt,
            $salt_separator,
            $signer_key,
            $rounds,
            $mem_cost,
        ]);
        $process->run();

        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) throw new \Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException($process);

        $result = (int) $process->getOutput();
    }

    return response()->json(['data' => [
        'result' => $result,
    ]]);
});
```

I created a python script in the root of the laravel project with something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import base64
import hashlib
import hmac
import sys

from Crypto.Cipher import AES

def generate_derived_key(
) -> bytes:
    # ... code from python repo
    return derived_key

def encrypt(signer_key: bytes, derived_key: bytes) -> bytes:
    # ... code from python repo
    return result
    

def verify_password(
    password: str,
    known_hash: str,
    salt: str,
    salt_separator: str,
    signer_key: str,
    rounds: int,
    mem_cost: int
) -> bool:
    # ... code from python repo
    return hmac.compare_digest(password_hash, known_hash)

result = verify_password(
    sys.argv[1], #password
    sys.argv[2], #password_hash
    sys.argv[3], #salt
    sys.argv[4], #salt_separator
    sys.argv[5], #signer_key
    int(sys.argv[6]), #rounds
    int(sys.argv[7]) #mem_cost
)

print( 1 if result else 0 )
```

You will need to import firebase registrants data into your Postgresql DB, and create a Laravel model, and then you can easily manage Firebase accounts from your Laravel PHP project.